# Evaluate $\sum \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2(n!)+1}.$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

My problem is to find the sum  of the following series 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2(n!)+1}.$$

I tried but I got struck. Any help/hints are appreciated!

Comment: Just to be clear, $2*(n!)$ or $(2n)!$?

Comment: Are you trying to find the numerical value of the sum, or an analytic value?

Comment: I want to find numerical value

Comment: If you just want a numerical value, you can ask [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=N[Sum[%28-1%29^%28n%2B1%29%2F%282*%28n!%29%2B1%29%2C{n%2C1%2C100}]%2C50]).  e.g. following command `N[Sum[(-1)^(n+1)/(2*(n!)+1),{n,1,100}],50]` gives you $$\approx 0.19339170956147280483786633319521181226736743695924$$